# is it possible to add more than one control on the same gridview row cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to add next to a label, (on the same cell if possible) a '[...]' as link button or other control that would make any postback.

In my gridview databound event i have this code,
I have two  `ItemTemplates` that contains  `asp:labels`

ItemTemplate on cell 7 is invisible, just stores the full text that was binded on sp call.

```
protected void grid_DataBound( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
  GridViewRow header = (GridViewRow)grid.HeaderRow;
  GridViewRowCollection rows = (GridViewRowCollection)grid.Rows;
  
  foreach ( GridViewRow row in rows )
  {
  ( (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)row.Cells[7].FindControl( "lblAux" 
  ) ).Text = ( (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)row.Cells[6].FindControl( "lblText" ) ).Text;

  ( (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)row.Cells[6].FindControl( "lblText" ) ).Text = 
  ( (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)row.Cells[6].FindControl( "lblText" ) ).Text.Substring( 0, 10 );

  System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btn = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
  btn.Text = "[...]";

//More code to open a script displaying the full text on popup.

  ->This doesnt work
  row.Cells[6].Add(btn);
  I want to be able to add the control next to the label without having to create a new cell, is this possible? if so any help would be appreciated, thanks!.

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, if this ever happens to somebody else this was my solution:

On the .aspx gridview i added the linkbutton control on the same item template that contains the label

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OBSERVATIONS">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OBSERVATIONS") %>' > 
    </asp:Label>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOpenInDialog" visible="false" runat="server" Text="[...]" OnClick="lnkOpenInDialog_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

On Databound function i set the command name of the linkbutton.

Comment: Often, when the grid starts to get fancy, then I switch over to a list view. each column does not then require the template tags. But, yes, as you show, you are 100% free to have multiple controls in the one column/cell.